# How to update object (array) from Child Component to Parent Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have two components the add-contact-component (child component) and the contact-manager-component(parent component) How can I use output and event emitter for my object array to be pass from child to parent component whenever I press the update button? Also is there a way for the create button to be changed to update button whenever I click the edit button on the parent component?

[image: Contact App]

> **Child Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MyContact } from '../models/myContact';
import { ContactService } from '../services/contact.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-contact',
  templateUrl: './add-contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-contact.component.css']
})

export class AddContactComponent implements OnInit {
  public loading:boolean = false;
  @Input() contact:MyContact = {} as MyContact;
  @Output() contactChange:EventEmitter<MyContact> =new EventEmitter<MyContact>();

 
  public editMode:boolean = false;
  

  constructor(private contService:ContactService, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
   
  onSubmit(contactForm: { value: any; }) {
    this.contService.CreateContacts(this.contact).subscribe((data:MyContact)=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/']).then(()=>{
        window.location.reload();
      });       
 
  }
  
  update() {
  this.contactChange.emit(this.contact);
 }


 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm)" #contactForm="ngForm" novalidate #contactChange>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <input required [(ngModel)]="contact.name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name (required)" #name="ngModel" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!name?.valid && (name?.dirty || name?.touched)">Name Required</div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <input required email [(ngModel)]="contact.email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email (required)" #email="ngModel" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!email?.valid && (email?.dirty || email?.touched)">Email Not Valid</div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <input required [(ngModel)]="contact.mobile" name="mobile" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile (required)" #mobile="ngModel" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!mobile?.valid && (mobile?.dirty || mobile?.touched)">Mobile Required</div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="contact.company" name="company" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company (optional)" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="contact.title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title (optional)" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="contact.photo" name="photo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Photo Url (optional)" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid">Create</button>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <button (click)="update()" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Parent Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MyContact } from '../models/myContact';
import { ContactService } from '../services/contact.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-manager',
  templateUrl: './contact-manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-manager.component.css']
})
export class ContactManagerComponent implements OnInit {
  public loading:boolean = false;
  public contacts:MyContact[] = [];
  public contactId:string | null = null;

  selectedContact:MyContact = new MyContact();

  constructor(private contService:ContactService, private router:Router, private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllContactData(); 
  }

  getAllContactData(){
    this.loading = true;
    this.contService.getAllContacts().subscribe((data:MyContact[])=>{
      this.contacts = data;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
  deleteContact(contactId:string | undefined){
    if(contactId){
      this.contService.deleteContacts(contactId).subscribe((data:{})=>{
        this.getAllContactData();        
      });
    }
  }

 showDetails(contact:MyContact) {
  this.selectedContact=Object.assign({},contact)
  this.isupdate = true;
  console.log(this.isupdate);
  console.log(this.selectedContact);
}

update(contact: MyContact) {
*INSERT FUNCTION HERE FOR contact to be send to the array object MyContact in parent component*
}

}
```

```html
<app-add-contact [contact]="selectedContact" (contactChange)="update($event)" *ngIf="visible "></app-add-contact>

<div class="container mt-3">
   
    <h2>Contact List</h2>
     
    <table class="table table-bordered border-secondary border-5 table-light table-hover">
      <thead class="table table-bordered table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts ; let i = index">
          <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ contact.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ contact.mobile }}</td>
          <td><div class="d-flex align-items- justify-content-around">
            <a routerLink="/contacts/view/{{contact.id}}" class="btn btn-warning my-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View Contact Details">
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Contact" (click)="showDetails(contact)">Edit</button>
            <a routerLink="/contacts/edit/{{contact.id}}" class="btn btn-primary my-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Contact">
                <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-danger my-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete Contact" (click)="deleteContact(contact.id)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

I've been stuck on this one for a few days already.

Tried to follow this tutorial still to no avail. Kept getting errors and data not reflecting.
[Angular @input, @output & EventEmitter](https://tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-input-output-eventemitter/#:%7E:text=%40Input%20defines%20the%20input%20property,parent%20listens%20to%20these%20events.)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing handling the `output` from the child component into the parent one.

In your parent template HTML, you probably have the child component, and you are passing down the `contact` `@Input`:

```html
<app-add-contact [contact]="theContactYouWanToPass"></app-add-contact>
```

Since your child component is emitting an event when updating the contact, you need to specify that event in your parent component, so it can listen to that particular event:

```html
<app-add-contact 
  [contact]="theContactYouWanToPass"
  (contactChange)="update($event)">
</app-add-contact>
```

The name for that event has to be the same as the one declared in your child component.

> I've been stuck on this one for a few days already.

I recommend reading the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) from Angular website

Comment: Yep I somehow made it work. Thanks. 

Follow up question though when I pass the update contact to the parent component it is not saving on my fake json database. Though it's reflecting it will be removed when I refresh the browser.

`update(contact: MyContact) {  
this.contacts = this.contacts.map(cont => {
  if(contact.id === cont.id) {
    return contact;
  }
  return cont;
})`